# how to make gridview with image and checkbox in fragment?

Tags: android, gridview, baseadapter

I am using custom gridview with image and checkbox in my fragment,user can select the image using checkbox,following is my code with adapter can any one tell what is the issue with this,thanks in advance

**ISSUE**

```
 holder.img.setOnClickListener(new ImageClickListener(context, holder,thumbnailsselection));
            holder.img.setImageResource(imageId[position]);
            holder.tv.setChecked(thumbnailsselection[position]);
            holder.id = position;
```

can not resolve Imageclicklistner

Fragmentcode

```
public class ShareAFriend extends Fragment{

    private int count;
    private Bitmap[] thumbnails;
    private boolean[] thumbnailsselection;
    private String[] arrPath;


    int[] flags = new int[]{
            R.drawable.propicone,
            R.drawable.propicone,
            R.drawable.propicone,
            R.drawable.propicone,
            R.drawable.propicone,
            R.drawable.propicone,
            R.drawable.propicone,
            R.drawable.propicone,
            R.drawable.propicone
    };

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.share_a_friend, container, false);
        GridView imagegrid = (GridView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageGrid);
      //  imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter();
       imagegrid.setAdapter(new CustAdapter(getActivity(),flags));


        return rootView;


    }


    public class CustAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        String[] result;
        Context context;
        int[] imageId;
        private LayoutInflater inflater = null;

        public CustAdapter(Context cont, int[] prgmImages) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

            context = cont;
            imageId = prgmImages;
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.
                    getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return result.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        public class Holder {
            CheckBox tv;
            ImageView img;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Holder holder = new Holder();
            View rowView;
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.griditem, null);
            holder.tv = (CheckBox) rowView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_checkbox);
            holder.img = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image);

            holder.tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) view;
                    int id = cb.getId();

                    if (thumbnailsselection[id]){
//cb.setChecked(false);
                        thumbnailsselection[id] = false;
                    } else {
//cb.setChecked(true);
                        thumbnailsselection[id] = true;
                    }
                }
            });
            holder.img.setOnClickListener(new ImageClickListener(context, holder,thumbnailsselection));
            holder.img.setImageResource(imageId[position]);
            holder.tv.setChecked(thumbnailsselection[position]);
            holder.id = position;

            return rowView;
        }

    }

    }
```

Comment: What is there in `Imageclicklistner`?

Comment: to set selection on image

Comment: What issue you are facing?

Comment: @PiyushGupta read the question there i mentioned that can not resolve Imageclicklistner..and also id can not resolve

Comment: Is ImageClickListener in your custom adapter class?

Comment: String[] result; .... where it is initialised?

Comment: @PiyushGupta yes i already defined

Comment: @PiyushGupta how to make image selection with checkbox thats what i need

Comment: For that use `CheckedTextView` instead of `CheckBox`.

Comment: @PiyushGupta I am not using text anywhere..

Comment: You can set empty text for that if you don't need. It will work if you tap on image too.

Comment: can you tell how to use it with gridview?

Comment: Same you need to inflate that layout (in which your image and checkedtextView) in your custom adapter.

Comment: @PiyushGupta can you help me with that..

Comment: @Jolly Wait for a while. I will post my answer. Before that show screenshot how you need?

Comment: some thing like this http://www.technotalkative.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/technotalkative-select-multiple-photos-from-gallery.png

Comment: @PiyushGupta did you see that image